# Replacing + sign with sum of those 2 numbers in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, integer

I have a column in dataframe named price that has values like 100, 200, 2300,2300+200 so on.
How can i replace 2300+200 with sum of those 2 numbers i.e as 2500.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) in `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[10,'1000+1']})

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(pd.eval)
print (df)
    col
0    10
1  1001
```